# Java print screen program

Tags: java, awtrobot, printscreen

I am trying to use `Robot` in Java to make an image file of a print screen. So far I have:

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
 BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
 ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", new File("printscreen.bmp"));
```

But I can't seem to get it to create the file.

Comment: +1 to close this as the op realize the code is good as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s/printscreen.bmp/"printscreen.bmp"
```

Comment: Probably safe to assume the code in his program actually compiles. The missing quotes are likely an omission.

Comment: Probably, but with quotes works perfectly ( at least on my machine )

Comment: yeah I agree +1. @Ste T, is your post an exact copy/paste or did you type the code in?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if .bmp files are support. Oops, they are:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.asList( ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes() ) );
```

You can also use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class for some more general screen printing features.