# How to print all content of a form in java?

Tags: java, printing, jframe, jpanel

I've been trying to find a command or sample code that when you click a button it will print all the content inside the form.!

i am trying to recreate our invoice and have a database for it, it is also necessary that i print that content with that form as we are using it on a daily basis.

Comment: Where do you want to print all the content?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728397/print-the-whole-program-layout/16728708#16728708) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22242658#22242658) (check both answers) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed/17961911#17961911) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916)?

Comment: i would like to print it on a a4 sized paper. we raise invoice and our people does it manually. i would like to create a program that can create, save, edit and print the invoice.