# Save a drawn picture on a JPanel in a file [java]

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, png

I've made a code to draw on a `Jpanel`

```
frame1.add( new JPanel() {
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        //Drawnig Part
});
```

- Every thing is OK
- Now My question is  how to save what I've drawn on my `JPanel` in a file `a.PNG` or any other type
- I have spent a lot of time to write the `Drawing Part`, So it will be helpful if you can suggest a solution by changing the required parts of my code, instead of rewriting the whole code.

Comment: [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/swing-obtain-image-of-jframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you buffer your drawing operations with a BufferedImage, like so:

```
// This should not be done in the draw method, but rather when
// the frame is created. You should also make a new buffer image when
// the frame is resized. `frameWidth` and `frameHeight` are the
// frame's dimensions.
BufferedImage bufferImage = new BufferedImage(frameWidth, frameHeight,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D bufferGraphics = bufferImage.createGraphics();


// In your draw method, do the following steps:

// 1. Clear the buffer:
bufferGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

// 2. Draw things to bufferGraphics...

// 3. Copy the buffer:
g2.drawImage(bufferImage, null, 0, 0);

// When you want to save your image presented in the frame, call the following:
ImageIO.write(bufferImage, "png", new File("frameImage.png"));
```

[The Java Tutorial on Creating and Drawing to an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html), along with the [ImageIO API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) might be helpful should you require more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) for more details, but essentially you can do something like...

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
// Draw what ever you want to to the graphics context
g2d.dispose();

ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("My Awesome Drawing.png"));
```

If you can't separate the drawing logic from your panel, you could simply use the `Graphics` context from the `BufferedImage` to paint the the component with.

Have a look at [Exporting a JPanel to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690275/exporting-a-jpanel-to-an-image/17690351#17690351) and [Print the whole program layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728397/print-the-whole-program-layout/16728708#16728708) for examples

Comment: what's the relation between g2d and img ?

Comment: Well, that would depend on what you painted to it, since, I don't have the paint code I have no idea what might have happended

Comment: thank you so much it's working but it's missing one small point , it's how to draw on *g2d* what i've drawn on *g2*

Comment: See the last two links? Those show you how you can paint a component to a BufferedImage ;)